# jsf selectonemenu dynamically setvalue

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, selectonemenu

I am trying to set the value of a `SelectOneMenu` programmatically but the value doesn't get set.

Tried searching the solution a lot but couldn't find a satisfactory answer:

Here is the code. To Create the `SelectOneMenu`:

```
SelectOneMenu yesNoDropdown = new SelectOneMenu();
List<SelectItem> items = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
items.add(new SelectItem("", ""));
items.add(new SelectItem("yes", "Yes"));
items.add(new SelectItem("no", "No"));

UISelectItems selectOptions = new UISelectItems();
selectOptions.setValue(items);

yesNoDropdown.getChildren().add(selectOptions);
yesNoDropdown.setId("yes-no");
yesNoDropdown.setRequired(true);
```

And I am trying to set the value using this code:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
UIViewRoot rootView = context.getViewRoot();
SelectOneMenu yesNoDropdown = (SelectOneMenu) rootView.findComponent("formId:yes-no");
yesNoDropdown.setValue("no");
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("formId");
```

Not sure what is wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just use XHTML instead of Java. It's a more natural language to specify the component tree.

Comment: I solved it just now : did this : yesNoDropdown.setSubmittedValue("no");

Comment: Thanks @BalusC for your suggestion. I would have done this in xhtml (that is easier and prettier), but my requirement doesn't allow me to do that.

Comment: There's **nothing** that's impossible in XHTML and only possible in Java.

Comment: @BalusC - You were right and I admit that I was lazy enough to rewrite java code to xhtml. But I did it (Easier and Cleaner). Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it just now : did this :

```
yesNoDropdown.setSubmittedValue("no");
```

Thanks!